# Store custom class a property

Tags: python, scripting, development

I am trying to store a custom class in a property group. I tried doing it this way:

```
class WowRootPropertyGroup(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):

MODS = MODS_chunk()
MODN = MODN_chunk()
MODD = MODD_chunk()
```

It only works until and addon is reloaded or blender is restarted because the default constructor is called on this reloading and the data stored gets wiped. Is there any workaround for it to preserve it permanently?